# Question about a submodule

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $R=\prod_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\mathbb{Z}$ and $M$ be $R$ regarded as $R$-module is usual way.

The submodule $N=\bigoplus_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\mathbb{Z}$ is it finitely generated?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

An element of $N$ is only nonzero in finitely many coordinates.

A finite set of elements of $N$, therefore, can only generate a submodule that is nonzero only on finitely many coordinates. (All the coordinates where the generators are nonzero.)

But $N$ is nonzero in infinitely many coordinates.

Comment: How do you prove that: An element of $N$ is only nonzero in finitely many coordinates.?

Comment: @siwar I think that you will gain a lot more from figuring this one out for yourself, rather than letting me spoonfeed the whole thing to you.

Comment: Can you give me a hint please ?

Comment: @siwar This is basically an entire answer: the union of finitely many finite sets is a finite set.

Comment: I tried but I get stacked, please can you help me because I am reviewing for my Exam and knowing how to prove this, will help me a lot in my Exam.  Thanks

Comment: @siwar where did you get stuck?

Comment: I thought a lot but I did not understand why An element of 
$N$ is only nonzero in finitely many coordinates.?

Comment: @siwar Because that is the definition of the direct sum of modules. It consists of the sequences having only finitely many nonzero terms.